# Stating "Because of private meeting they didn’t let me post more stuff." in a formal form

Tags: grammaticality, vocabulary, language-formation

I would say “in consideration of private gathering, they didn’t let me post more stuff on my IG stories” OR “ in light of private meeting, I couldn’t ... “

Is it well formed? Or natives saying in another way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I’m going to a private meeting and I need to post some IG stories! However, after that I have to write something like that! I’m trying to say to my audiences that because of private meeting they didn’t let me post more stuff. I’m looking for something formal and native way

Comment: What is wrong with what you just said? "Because of private meeting they didn’t let me post more stuff." it is clear, the only question might be who do you mean by "they". Choose clarity, formal lingo is good for politicians or those who are trying to choose confusion over clarity.

Comment: It should be "...of the private..."